# How can I reset my in-game settings (on mac)?

Tags: league-of-legends

I screwed up my in-game settings by pressing on the <kbd>Restore Defaults</kbd> button in the Settings menu, thinking it would restore my settings. However, now I can't press the undo button or sell any items.

I've already found the `game.cfg` and `input.ini` files, but I can't open them. Does anyone know (after I've opened the file(s)) what I need to type in them so I can reset the settings?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [relevant post](http://boards.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/c/help-support/pGwELzEK-left-click-not-working?comment=0006) by Riot on the same issue "Left Click Not Working":

> We recently enabled server-side keybindings. This means that your
>   settings are now account bound and will follow you from computer to
>   computer and **won't change even if you re-install**.
>
> The thing we don't understand is how your settings got into this state
>   without you knowing. The symptoms you describe are the same as if you
>   follow a guide like this:
>   https://www.reddit.com/r/leagueoflegends/comments/1bo2nk/guide_to_easy_kiting_left_click_attack
>
> Can you do a huge favor in helping other players and answer the
>   following questions?
>
> 1: Have you ever manually edited your Input.ini or PersistedSetttings.json files?
>   2: Do you share your computer with anyone who plays LoL? (or logged in at a PC Bang / Friend's Computer / etc)
>   3: What kind of mouse do you use?
>   4: Do you use any macros or software related to input?
>   5: Do you share your account?
>
> If you want to fix your problem follow these steps (order is important):
>   **1) Login
>
>   2) Delete your Config folder (this includes PersistedSettings.json and input.ini)
>
>   3) Go into a custom game (you should now have default settings)
>
>   4) Exit the custom game (your default settings will now be saved to the server)**

Answer (score -2):

Apparently this worked for someone else : [Forums](http://boards.euw.leagueoflegends.com/en/c/help-support-en/7YuzlaPU-deleting-inputini-does-not-reset-my-keybindings)

> Try it again (the editing or deleting, wich one you want to do im not sure ^_^), but this time also delete the file called PersistedSettings.json for the changes to stick.